# postgres - Display timestamp column with and without TIMEZONE paramter setting

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp

To begin with, the [official document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) says the following:

> To address these difficulties, we recommend using date/time types that
>   contain both date and time when using time zones. We do not recommend
>   using the type time with time zone (though it is supported by
>   PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL
>   standard). PostgreSQL assumes your local time zone for any type
>   containing only date or time.

And on display of time stamp data, it says:

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

Therefore, I have defined columns as `timestamp` data type and inserting into the table as `"2018-05-24 09:30:00+05:30"`. Based on the points mentioned above, I was hoping to see time stamp (in SELECT query output) in UTC i.e. `2018-05-24 04:00:00` because `TIME ZONE` was set to UTC. And, when I change the parameter as

```
SET TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
```

I was hoping to see `2018-05-24 09:30:00`. But, regardless of the time zone parameter, I see query output as `2018-05-24 09:30:00`. How does this observation tally with the documentation?

The insert to the database was done with Javascript whereas other operations were done with `psql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical phrasing in the documentation is "timezone-aware dates and times". This is referring to the `timestamptz` type.

Rephrasing the docs: When you want timezones to be happening during input/output, use `timestamptz` type.

1. This type is rendered/output in the session time zone. That is, all values will be offset from UTC and be shown with a zone suffix, e.g. `+05:30`.
2. Literals without any zone information are interpreted/input as being in the session time zone. That is, `2018-05-24 09:30:00` will act as though it has the suffix `+05:30`.
3. Zone information in literals are considered rather than discarded. That is, `2018-05-24 09:30:00+05:30` will be converted to `04:00` UTC.

(The input side seems a little magic, but it's because literals are *untyped* until they are cast or get used with something typed. That is, `'2018-05-24 09:30:00+05:30'` by itself is *neither* timestamp nor timestamptz. It's a pile of characters that are interpreted when you insert into a table or compare to a column.)

Comment: With `timestamptz`, did you mean `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`? Because, I am using the column data type as `TIMESTAMP`. In which case, the setting of `TIME ZONE` parameter is not applicable?

Comment: [Yep!](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> `timestamptz` is accepted as an abbreviation for `timestamp with time zone`; this is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: You can experiment with the behavior of different combinations using type casts: `SELECT 'some value'::timestamp, 'some value'::timestamptz`